# ListView Touch is disabled with button

Tags: android, listview

**I am using custom listview when i placing  the button in custome view it is   disabling the item touch or itemlongpress listener  ...

How to use button click and listview touch simultaneously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem here is , Listview having button as a child, Button will take the priority of onClick. Do the following thing

- Set the property of Button to setFocusable(false);It will enable the OnClick on ListView.
- For Click on Button - use onTouch instead of onClick. Which will allow you to click on button as well

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the ListView tag where you define it in xml.